# npm start won't run my project locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have just started with ReactJS. I cannot start the server using `npm start` since start script is not in `package.json`, when I include start in scripts, and then try `npm start`, this shows up

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error menaluxe@1.0.0 start: `search.min.js start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the menaluxe@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I would be really, really thankful if someone can help me with this.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "menaluxe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "search.min.js start",
    "build": "webpack && uglifyjs ./assets/build/postadd.js -c -m -o ./assets/build/postadd.min.js && uglifyjs ./assets/build/search.js -c -m -o ./assets/build/search.min.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "bootstrap-without-jquery": "^1.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "flux": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "images-require-hook": "^1.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^2.1.2",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "react-pure-render": "^1.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "superagent": "^3.2.1",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.4",
    "unminified-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: try npm run start ..

Comment: there is nothing like npm server

Comment: sorry what I mean to say is, when VS code debugger has to run after server is running locally with the application.

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala it is still giving out the same error

Comment: @CheekyVibes, Add package.json HERE! I think you didn't do npm install, did you?

Comment: @Aditya no but I have package.json and node_modules already in the project

Comment: I have updated the question to include my package.json file, please look into it.

Comment: could you share your webpack file?

Comment: Why do you have to update the start command? Also, what is search.min.js?

Comment: search.min.js is possibly the file i'd like to debug and run, it is the react code that has been compiled to javascript

Comment: Please note that when I open index.html from the browser as well, every aspect of the project is running except the react elements.

Comment: try using webpack-dev-server to run your app

Comment: although webpack is enough for packaging minifying your app.

Comment: Try making changes in in your script as `"start": "node search.min.js",`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have already run `npm install`.

Depends on how your project is set up, you may not need a `start`.

If your webpack is doing the start local server for you, you can just do `npm build`, and see what happens.

If that does not start a local server, you can always build the project using `npm build` and then start the local server yourself by using `http-server` package inside the build folder. When you run `build`, it should generate a new folder called `build` or `dist` or something like that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Install this package globally, then in the terminal type `http-server ./build` or dist or wherever your project builds to.

Comment: "npm run-scripts build" generated this, and +100 more lines of error log:
Hash: 03b53bdab7356c613c26
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 79681ms
     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 search.js  5.55 MB       0  [emitted]  search
postadd.js  5.66 MB       1  [emitted]  postadd
    + 284 hidden modules

WARNING in search.js from UglifyJs

Comment: @CheekyVibes could you post your webpack file? and post your webpack error. Not the whole thing, but just the part identify the error message.

Comment: could you post your error message and your webpack file?

Comment: and from what you send, it didn't generate any error? If it didn't generate any error, did it create a folder or a few files somewhere in your directory?

Comment: Hey, after looking into it, my project file already has a build folder and it has 4 js files there

Comment: It had that build folder because you `build` it. When you run `npm build`. it creates those files for you. After fixing this you should definitely read up on the build process, and how it works.

Comment: ok now install http-server, by typeing `npm install http-server -g`. Then do `http-server ./build`

Comment: I have installed and entered the command, now, I cannot connect to it, whenever I type the url in chrome it says: "Page not found"

Comment: The server is running

Comment: ok good! could you list those files inside your build folder?

Comment: 1) postadd.js
2) postadd.min.js
3) search.js
4) search.min.js

Comment: it sounds like it, i wonder if it would be easier to just use parcel. Do you have a index.html? If so, you can try to install parcel: `npm install -g parcel-bundler`, then `parcel index.html`

Comment: yes I have index.html, and yes I also have two entry points if that's what you are talking about I looked into my webpack file and at "entry" found two react js files.

Comment: Ok, I ran what you said, and now, the page is loading on localhost, one react element is working which is on index.html, but the next one is not working it is on a button on another page. I'm trying to navigate to the page, the page loads, but not the react element.

Comment: Next time I would recommend research a bit on this problem before asking on Stackoverflow, as you can see there is hardly enough information for us to know what is wrong with your project.

Comment: you can use `parcel` with multiple entry points if need as well. https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/1119

Comment: I think I will leave you to figure out the rest, it shouldn't be too difficult. Although I would talk to your peers and firgure out a prefered way in your company to run this app. They might already know how to config webpack.

Comment: Thank you so much @Leogoesger you helped me so much, I would try to read more about build after this is done as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For development use
Use Webpack dev server

```
npm install webpack-dev-server@latest webpack-cli@latest
```

Add to package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build-dev": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

Add webpack.config.js if you dont have

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports ={
  return {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/'
    }
  };
}
```

From terminal

```
npm run build-dev
```

Comment: you have to add devServer part if you have everything working

Comment: the problem is that my react application has two entry points. and also it is half built with simple javascript and the other half with react

Comment: is that interdependent.. can you post your webpack.config.js

Comment: yes if they do not violate anything or any use case

Answer (score 0):

Please change script block in package.json like below  :

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject" }
```

then run "npm run start " in your terminal

Comment: can you explain please those script. how does they work?

Comment: I have tried that, it also throws an error because it does not know what "react-scripts" is

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala In my knowledge, when you write npm, that is when scripts are accessed to read more commands after that. If I write npm start and start is not defined in "scripts" then it won't work.

Comment: @ShubhamBhewanewala this block explain some shortcut like start , build, test , ejetc  .
so if you does not recognize react-scripts , you have to install it , 
"npm i react-scripts --save"